# Ether transaction does not reflect in ganache

Tags: solidity, ether, dapps, javascript

Hi am developing a etherium DAPP.

In that for every user registration some ether will get transfer from user to contract...

Everything work perfect but the transacted ether is not reflecting in ganache accounts....

**Account balance should be 144.44**
[image]

**Metamask transaction is fine for 5.5 Ether**

[image]

[image]

**Transaction details in Ganache**

[image]

**JS CODE**

```
createUser: function (){
        console.log("First Name: "+ $('#firstName').val());
        console.log("Last Name: "+ $('#lastName').val());
        console.log("Age: "+ $('#age').val());
        console.log("Is city: "+ $('#city').val());

      if ($('#firstName').val() && $('#lastName').val()  && $('#age').val()  && $('#city').val() ){        
           web3.eth.getAccounts(function (error,accounts){
          if (error){
              App.showError(error);
          }
         App.currentAccount = curacc;
         // App.currentAccount = "0xAa1e9e6f830c2C07FCA79D9cE2ebC81310541A1b";
          console.log("curr acc: "+ App.currentAccount);

          let tipAmount = window.web3.utils.toWei('5.5', 'Ether');
          console.log("tipAmount" + tipAmount);

          App.contracts.HelloWorld.deployed().then(function(instance){
            return instance.createUser.sendTransaction($('#firstName').val(), $('#lastName').val(), 
            $('#age').val() , $('#city').val(), {from:App.currentAccount , value: tipAmount})
          }).then(function(result){
              App.showMessage('Submitted data saved Successfully....');
              App.ShowSavedUser();
          }).catch(function (error){
              App.showError(error);
          })
        })
      }
      else{
        console.log("Data not filled for all fields....");
          App.showError('Please fill all fields...');
      }
    },
```

**SOLIDITY CODE**

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

contract HelloWorld {

uint public userCount = 0;


constructor() public{
    createUser ("Monicka", "Akilan", 30, "Chennai");
}

  struct User {
    uint id;
    string firstName;
    string lastName;
    uint age;
    string city;    
    uint tipAmount;
    address payable author;
  }
event profileTips(string firstName, string lastName, uint age, 
 string city, uint tipAmount, address payable author);

mapping(uint => User) public Users;

 function createUser(string memory _firstName, string memory _lastName, uint _age, 
 string memory  _city) public payable{
    userCount ++;
    // address(msg.sender).transfer(msg.value);
     Users[userCount] = User(userCount, _firstName, _lastName, _age, _city, 20, msg.sender);
    emit profileTips(_firstName, _lastName, _age,  _city, msg.value,  msg.sender);
 }
}
```

Can anyone help me solve this sync issue....

**Thanks in Advance**

Comment: i don’t see what is out of sync? The contract recieved 5.5 ether you send to it

Comment: Does metamask shows the correct balance? The code has `address(msg.sender).transfer(msg.value)` commented out, perhaps you were addressing a previous version with that code uncommended?

Comment: yeah the balance is showing in metamask